Is there a lower bound for the order of the automorphsim group of direct product of cyclic groups?
I'm trying to find the finitely generated abelian groups A such that A is isomorphic to $Aut(A)$, which I suspect to be the trivial group. I know that the order of the automorphism group of a cyclic group is given by Euler's totient function $ϕ(n)ϕ(n)$, which is strictly smaller than the order of the group $n$ for $n>2$. Therefore, if we have a finitely-genearted abelian group A such that A is cyclic or product of cyclic groups of order relative prime order -- which then A would be isomorphic to a cyclic group -- then the order must be strictly smaller than the order of A.
However, I cannot find a similar relationship for the order of the automorphism group of a direct product of cyclic groups, which I suspect must be strictly greater than the order of the group, except for trivial cases.
For instance, if we consider $G=Zp×Zp$ (where p is prime), the order of $Aut(G)$ is $(p^2−1)(p^2−p)$, which is strictly greater than $∣G∣$=$p^2$. I think that adding more cyclic groups to the direct product would increase the order of the automorphism group, making it impossible for $∣Aut(G)∣$ to be less than or equal to $∣G∣$ for any nontrivial direct product.
However, I am struggling to prove this formally. Is there a systematic way to show that the order of the automorphism group of a direct product of cyclic groups is always strictly greater than the order of the group itself (except in trivial cases)? Is there a lower bound for ∣Aut(G)∣ in terms of ∣G∣ -- given that G is a direct product of cyclic groups? Any help or insight would be appreciated!
Edit:
It has been noticed that the order is not the way to think about it, since $Aut(Z2xZ4)$ has order 8, so it is not enough to show it. Is there any requirement for Aut(A) to be abelian, being A a finitely-generated abelian group?

Order is the wrong thing to use here IMO. Do you think these automorphism groups for direct products are Abelian?

You can also see this question and answer, though you don't need the full result that's proved there.

Also one last thing to note, $Aut(C_2\times C_4)$ has order $8$, so order alone isn't really enough.

What about products of cyclic groups of coprime order? Their automorphisms should still be smaller than the groups themselves.
